# gridview index type error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView in which I'm redirecting to popup from bounded button click which has its row value from `id`.

But its throwing an exception:

> index is out of range bigger than 127

I want to change type of index but its not working.

Here's my code:

```
protected void GridView1_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.Toint16(e.CommandArgument);

    TextBox1.Text = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[4].Text;
    TextBox2.Text = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[5].Text;
    TextBox3.Text = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[6].Text;
    TextBox4.Text = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[7].Text;
    TextBox5.Text = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[8].Text;
    TextBox6.Text = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[9].Text;
}
```

Comment: Please format your question properly and improve the grammar because it's hard to understand what you want. Also, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: what i'm saying is that i want to change data type of index to double because id is much bigger than integer range and i use id of row to pop up its row information to new window but i got error in changing data type "cannot change strig or esle to int  " textbox 1 is for id which is cell no 4 when ever i click id bigger then 127 i get erorrr on index out of range

Comment: Please clarify your original post instead of commenting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in gridview1.Rows)
{
    if ((int)gridview1.DataKeys[gvRow.DataItemIndex].Value == index)
    {
        gridview1.SelectedIndex = gvRow.DataItemIndex;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to find the `index`:

### Option 1:

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

int index = row.RowIndex;
```

### Option 2:

In your button in .aspx add:

```
CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'
```

And in .cs:

```
int index = e.CommandArgument;
```

### Option 3:

Try it with `ToInt32` instead of `ToInt16`:

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
```